# Load Balancer unable to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

To achieve **HTTPS** on my domain name Which is connected to my newly created **Elastic Beanstalk** Application.
I have configured my EB Environment as follows:-

1. My server is set to Apache.

2.Modified my capacity:-

[image]

3.Added a listener to my **classic load balancer**(Rest settings are kept default):-

[image]

4.Here's how I've configured my **Route53**:-

[image]

5. Here's my **Namecheap** config:-

[image]

I still can not achieve http to https. please help. Do ask for more information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because CLB **doesn't support redirection**. From [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/):

> Classic Load Balancers **can't redirect** HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

The easiest way to rectify the issue would be to **change CLB into ALB**, and then setup the redirection by following any of the AWS guides, e.g.:

- [How can I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS using an Application Load Balancer?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/)

Comment: In my EC2 I can see already a classic LB which must be from EB, so should I edit that LB or I should create a new LB?

Comment: @KakashiHatake In your EB env configuration page, you should find "load balancer" options and the ability to change the LB type.

Comment: I am inside EB-env=>configuration => Load balancer:- Here I can see **Modify Classic Load Balancer** and I don't see any way to change the type of LB

Comment: I can see Sessions, Cross-zone load balancing, Connection draining and Health check. Will ALB cost more?

Comment: @KakashiHatake You are right. I can't see this option now. If possible, you can create new EB environment with ALB. Guess LB type can't be change after its created.